# How did Karen Pomeroy know about Frank?

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-darko

Just saw the movie *Donnie Darko* and of course there are many unanswered questions... but how did his teacher Drew Barrymore as Karen Pomeroy know about Frank? There is a scene in which she mentions it to Donnie and as far as I know only the psychologist knew about it.

Comment: Can you quote the scene?  I just scanned through the script and could not see a mention of Frank in a scene with Karen.

Comment: @iandotkelly Karen was not with Frank, in the script its this part: "MS. POMEROY(whispering in his ear)Donnie, maybe you and Frank can read this one together."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note**: *This answer is based on the Director's Cut.*

---

Karen knows about Frank because Donnie told her (and his classmates). In a scene where Donnie is reciting a self-written poem on "Poetry Day" in his English class, he talks about Frank. Once he's done, Karen asks him who Frank his, to which he replies: "a six foot tall bunny rabbit".

So, that's why she knows about Frank and whispers in Donnie's ear: "Maybe you and Frank can read this one together."

However, it's most probably more subtle than that...

---

If you go by the in-universe book, Roberta Sparrow's *The Philosophy of Time Travel*, then it seems obvious that Karen is one of the Manipulated Living. In the scene we are concerned with, she is subconsciously nudging Donnie to follow Frank — to make him realize that his visions are *NOT* mere hallucinations.